# Can't create bucket using aws-sdk ruby gem. Aws::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a new computer and I'm trying to set up my AWS CLI environment so that I can run a management console I've created.

This is the code I'm running:

```
def create_bucket(bucket_args)
  AWS_S3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(signature_version: 'v4')
  AWS_S3.create_bucket(bucket_args)
end
```

Which raises this error:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.:
```

This was working properly on my other computer, which I no longer have access to. I remember debugging this same error on the other computer, and I thought I had resolved it by adding `signature_version = s3v4` to my `~/.aws/config` file. But this fix is not working on my new computer, and I'm not sure why.

To give some more context: I am using `aws-sdk (2.5.5)` and these `aws` cli specs: `aws-cli/1.11.2 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.4.0-38-generic botocore/1.4.60`

Comment: What AWS region are you trying to connenct to?

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby#configuration

Comment: Us east 1, and yes I've looked at yhat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the issue was that my aws credentials (in `~/.aws/credentials`) - specifically my secret token - were invalid.

The original had a slash in it:

xx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

which I didn't notice at first, so when I double clicked the token to select the word, it didn't include the first three characters. I then pasted this into the terminal when running `aws configure`.

To fix this, I found the correct, original secret acceess token and set the correct value in `~/.aws/credentials`.